# invalid method when including module in Activesupport testcase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, include

I created this module: support/mailer_macros.rb

```
module MailerMacros
  def last_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  end

  def reset_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []
  end
end
```

I want to access it from my testhelper, so I did this in test/test_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest/rails"
#require "capybara/rails"
require "minitest/rails/capybara"
require "support/mailer_macros"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  include MailerMacros
  reset_email

end
```

But when I run my tests, I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `reset_email' for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class
```

What's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including a module means that the module's methods are available as *instance* methods, not class methods. You're trying to run `reset_email` at the class level.

To fix this, `extend MailerMacros` instead of including it:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  extend MailerMacros
  reset_email

end
```